# how do I delete the data from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I used Cassandra 3.6 Database and the table definition is this.

```
CREATE TABLE sg.products (
    date_updated text,
    time_added int,
    id text,
    best_seller text,
    company text,
    PRIMARY KEY (date_updated, time_added, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_added ASC, id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Table have millions of data.

In "products" table I Drop the column best_seller, successfully Drop the column.
but when I check the space disk, it does not decree,

so I hit the query on google and I found this term "Tombstone",

so the Cassandra was not deleting the data, kind of save into tombstone.

Now my question is how do I delete the tombstone data?, so I can save the memory.

Or is there any way to save the memory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Tombstones drop**
Cassandra will fully drop those tombstones when a compaction triggers, only after `local_delete_time + gc_grace_seconds` as defined on the table the data belongs to. Remember that all the nodes are supposed to have been repaired within gc_grace_seconds to ensure a correct distribution of the tombstones and prevent deleted data from reappearing.

Comment: Thanks @ravan96 for fast ans, you mean after gc_grace_seconds "10 days" expire. I get the space which is occupy by deleted data.

Comment: Yes @Ganesh , You can read more about the same here - http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Answer (score 2):

See this line from your table definition:

```
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
```

That is the time period which tombstones will live for.  864000 seconds == 10 days.  Tombstones exist for that duration to allow them adequate time to be distributed to the other nodes in your cluster.  That way all of the other nodes are aware of the delete(s), and do not return the obsoleted values.

Once that 10 day period has passed, and the next time this table triggers compaction (after that 10 days), the tombstones will be removed.

Note that you can shorten that period by modifying that property on your table definition.  Just make sure that you're running repairs within that timeframe.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for fast ans, you mean after 10 days I get the space which is occupy by deleted data.

Comment: @Ganesh Yes.  As long as there aren't any snapshots holding a hard link to any of the SSTable files, the next time that table triggers compaction after 10 days, the tombstones and the underlying obsoleted data will be removed from disk.